# AWS EC2 + Nginx + SSL fro subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

Can anyone explain to me a little bit how I can install SSL on my AWS EC2. I read lots of article that those steps are simple but I tried couple of them and none of them works.

I have one AWS EC2

EC2 staic ip, 54.X.X.X
subdoamin, xxxx.ab.abc.com
security group: port from
custom 80, 443, 9000-9100
nginx redirect
aaa1.ab.abc.com:80 to aaa1.ab.abc.com:9001
aaa2.ab.abc.com:80 to aaa1.ab.abc.com:9002
aaa3.ab.abc.com:80 to aaa1.ab.abc.com:9003
...
aaa(n).ab.abc.com:80 to aaa1.ab.abc.com:900(n)

```
ngnix.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name ~^(aaa(?<site>[0-9]+)).ab.abc.com;
    location / {
        set $custom_port 90$site;
        if ($custom_port ~ "^.{3}$") {
            set $custom_port 900$site;
        }
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$custom_port;
    }
}
```

How can I install SSL into EC2 so no matter which subdomain I hit. it will have certificated?

```
Steps I have done.

$sudo service nginx stop
$git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot.git to use certbot to generate SSL key
$./certbot-auto certonly --manual --email test@gmail.com -d ab.abc.com
$mkdir -p /tmp/certbot/public_html/.well-known/acme-challenge
$cd /tmp/certbot/public_html
$printf "%s" <key> > .well-known/acme-challenge/<key>
$sudo $(command -v python2 || command -v python2.7 || command -v python2.6) -c "import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer; s=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', 80), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler);s.serve_forever()"

then I have

108.14.0.213 - - [09/Jul/2017 03:32:26] "GET /path? HTTP/1.1" 404 -
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 236, in serve_forever
    poll_interval)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 155, in _eintr_retry
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Providing your nginx config will be a good place to start from in helping you

Comment: thx, update my question to include nginx file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/defaule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you want to do is install an SSl certificate on your instance then the best would be to generate a CSR and sign one with a third party provider like trustsign. Note that your choice SSL Certificate in this case would have to be a wildcard ssl cert type given your name format above. Should be `*ab.abc.com`

If this is just a test server and you don't care about the security warning, then you can sign it your self as follow but you will have to accept the security warning when accessing the url from your browser

```
# openssl genrsa -out keyfile.key 2048
# openssl req -new -key keyfile.key -out certrequest.csr
# openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in certrequest.csr -signkey keyfile.key -out certificate.pem
```

You can then update your nginx config to look as follow:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path_to_your_public_Cert/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path_to_yourPrivate_key/keyfile.key;
    server_name ~^(aaa(?<site>[0-9]+)).ab.abc.com;
    location / {
        set $custom_port 90$site;
        if ($custom_port ~ "^.{3}$") {
            set $custom_port 900$site;
        }
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$custom_port;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is different between I use openssl and certbot to generate SSL key? I have tried to use certbot to generate with wildcard(*) domain that is doesnot accept wildcard and try to generate one key for one of my domain that keep getting 404 failure

Comment: One difference is that certbot will generate a free cert for you, but i have always signed my ssl cert with recognized third party. You can't use wildcard (*) with certbot. You have to enter all domain but comma seperated

Comment: how can I install SSL certificate on instance? I tried openssl already, but I get not secure sign on browser now like you said. i guess that is because I miss the SSL on machine? so how can I make my domain as secure?

Comment: For the solution I mentioned above, you will get the security warning if you have signed yourself which is what the last command does. However, for this solution, if you don't want to see the security warning, then you have to stop at step 2 that created `certrequest.csr`. you can then use the `csr` to a third party CA like trustsign or commodo to sign and send you the public key. This will cost you some few dollars.

Comment: If you don't want to spend and you are familiar with CMD then you can use certbot. Step by Step guild on how to do it is here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04